Move on statically allocated containers benefit
I am not using any heap allocation in my code, any benefit of using move semantics?
Should I be even move-ing anything?
template <typename TIterator1, typename TIterator2>
constexpr TIterator2 move(TIterator1 sb, TIterator1 se, TIterator2 db)
{
    while (sb != se)
    {
        *db =  std::move(*sb); // move instead of copy
        ++db;
        ++sb;
    }

    return db;
}

Not sure how move semantics work on static memory, as all I keep seeing is that its good for moving big heap objects.
Is there a way to check if copy or move is used?

I don't think the two concepts(heap and move semantics) are related that much here.

"as all I keep seeing is that its good for moving big heap objects...." How and where you do you see/observe that?

Objects can be move-only even if they don't involve allocations, for example std::unique_lock<T>. It always depends on the type. In any case, moving objects that have only copy constructors/assignment doesn't do any harm

Says that it transfers ownership... I am not even sure move helps in this code. correct me if I am wrong, but the memory must be copied, as it is later overwritten again

If you want to respond to a particular user (or simply want them to receive a notification), write @, e.g. @Homer512 in your comment. Anyway, I think it would help if you showed more of your code and use case. Us imagining what you do, what types you use and where you transfer ownership of what, does not help.

@Homer512 Thanks , good to learn there are classes that disable their copy semantics for safety!  but I am not sure that this is my case here..

@Homer512 The code is part of a big library for statically allocated containers.https://github.com/ETLCPP/etl/blob/master/include/etl/vector.h

Your vector is templated on T, and T can be move-only.

Copying a refcounted pointer (like std::shared_ptr) increases and decreases the reference count, moving it empties the source and does not affect the memory count.

Moves are useful to move objects from one place to another; whether or not you want to move them is not determined by how they have been allocated (operations don't make a distinction there -- copying a string always copies all characters), but it's entirely based on whether you still need the previous object (in which case you need to copy) or not (in which case you should move the object). I even move things like an std::shared_ptr if possible -- while the copy is cheap, the move is cheaper.


Should I be even move-ing anything?

You don't need to std::move things that you know don't benefit from moves, like ints. There is however no downside to "overusing" move in cases like your example.
Templates should use std::move (or std::forward), because they don't know whether they are being used for things that benefit from, or require, moves.

Is there a way to check if copy or move is used?

You can write a type that logs when it is moved or copied.
struct ObserveCopyMove
{
    ObserveCopyMove() { std::cout << "Default Construct"; }
    ObserveCopyMove(const ObserveCopyMove &) { std::cout << "Copy Construct"; }
    ObserveCopyMove(ObserveCopyMove &&) { std::cout << "Move Construct"; }
    ObserveCopyMove& operator=(const ObserveCopyMove &) { std::cout << "Copy Assign"; return *this; }
    ObserveCopyMove& operator=(ObserveCopyMove &&) { std::cout << "Move Assign"; return *this; }
};


"however no downside to "overusing" move." return std::move(local_var); prevents NRVO and actually .uses move-constructor.

@Jarod42 oops, there's always the exception

@Caleth can you give an example where there is benefit of moving a no heap data?

@XigiSchul any other resource besides a dynamic allocation. However "moving" an int is copying it. That's why templates use move: it benefits some places, and doesn't hurt the other cases

@Caleth Just don't see it.. what about an array of int ? does it help there? As I see it the second the function is over the statically allocated memory is destroyed with its memory. I can't be using( pointing to) that memory from a different place,  I must copy it..

@XigiSchul move is an optimisation for copy. In situations where there is no benefit, it is a copy.

@Caleth thanks, I think it hit me now that the class determines what and how is the best way for him to act, if it has move semantics it knows that is fine for him to have one, if not he will not have one, and copy is the way!
